# Multiple tsconfig.json issue with commonJS for node.js and es6 for reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0, tsconfig

My current folder structure for typescript:

```
ts_dev
--client
  *components.tsx
  *tsconfig.json

--server
  *server.ts
  *tsconfig.json
  --share
    *utility.ts
```

The Node.js **server** needs to use `commonjs` modules, and `es2015` for the **client** side components. I place the **share** folder used by both **client** and **server** under the **server** directory because it needs `commonJS` for Node.js.

tsconfig.json in **server**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonJS",
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../../src",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types": ["reflect-metadata","system"],
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json in client:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../../src",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "types": ["reflect-metadata","system"],
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

However I find that the scripts in `share` are always complied in es6 (Use export,import etc) instead of commonJS, which breaks my server. I suspect it's caused by the tsconfig in the `client`. What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `include` option in each `tsconfig.json` file with file globs, to limit what files get compiled via each config file.

I solved a similar problem of mine by using different `outDirs`. What I think is happening to you is that you're compiling the source files twice, and the last time compiles the JS to `es2015`, overwriting the first. In other words, the `server` version gets compiled first, then the `client` version is compiled and overwrites it, because the outputs are going to the same directory.

Comment: Wait, directories are same, yes, but file names are different. What's in that case? What if I want to compile one `*.ts` file to `commonjs` and second to web (i. e. `none` module)?

Comment: @vintproykt can you use file globs in corresponding include sections to match the file names you want included by that particular config file?

Comment: I ended up with one non-obvious (at first) conclusion that I need to separate these directories in independent repositories and deal with monorepo architecture of further project. It is now application that I was needing as non-module and Visual Studio Code extension, both don't have compilation conflicts anymore!

Answer (score 1):

you already have the separated directory and separated tsconfig file.
it means u can generate outDir via from ur separated tsconfig file.
or
if u want to use one tsconfig.json file and generate es6 and commonjs.
so, try this one.

---

**file structure**

***Before tsc combile***

```
├── project/
|    └─ tsx
|    |   └─ hello.tsx
|    ├── package.json
|    ├── tsconfig.json
|    └── tsconfig-cjs.json
```

***After tsc combile***

```
├── project/
|    └─ out
|         ├─ es6
|         |   └─ hello.js
|         └─ cjs
|            └─ hello.js
|    └─ tsx
|        └─ hello.tsx
|    ├── package.json
|    ├── tsconfig.json
|    └── tsconfig-cjs.json
```

---

**code for package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.json && tsc -p tsconfig-cjs.json"
}
```

***code for tsconfig-cjs.json***

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": "./out/cjs"
  },
}
```